# How to count the total documents in phalcon mongodb collection

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

I need to count the total users from users collection in phalcon that should not include some users.

I have query the result in mongo shell:

```
db.users.find({"_id": {"$ne": ObjectId("5704a9f3f0616e61138b4618")}}).count()
```

And it works fine.

But when i query using phalcon mongo model it return nothing. Is there anything i missed on the following query?

```
Users::count([
            'conditions' => [
                '_id' => [
                    ['$ne' => new \MongoId($user_id)]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Users::count(array(
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            '_id' => array('$ne' => new \MongoId($user_id))
        )
    )
));
```

Basically, you need an array to wrap the where clause.
And if you prefer square brackets, try the following:

```
Users::count([
    [
        'conditions' => [
            '_id' => ['$ne' => new \MongoId($user_id)]
        ]
    ]
]);
```